# How to only get the final summary with Behave

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bdd, python-behave

I'm using a `main.py` to run all my `.feature` files this is how it looks like:

[image]

```py
import os


def main():
    os.system("behave features\logo_presence.feature")
    os.system("behave features\sign_in.feature")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm also using `behave.ini` with these values:

```
[behave]
stderr_capture=False
stdout_capture=False
log_capture=False
show_timings=False
verbose=False
color =True
quiet=True
show_source=False
```

My  problem is that I only want the final summary of the scenarios I'm running
but instead, I get all this:

[image]

I'm not interested in the chromedriver version that's get printed after every single test case or what feature I'm running I just want a group of summaries each representing each feature I ran in order.

I tried the summary command explained in the [doc](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#cmdoption-summary) but that didn't really help me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you already added most of the relevant options to `behave.ini`, but the repeating message is driven by the webdriver manager.

One solution could be suppressing `webdriver_manager` logs via the `WDM_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable:

```
import os

os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
```

Additionally, if you don't want `behave` to output the scenarios text you could play around with the formatter. e.g.

```
behave -k -f progress
```

From the [docs](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#cmdoption-f):

- `-f` Specify a [formatter](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatters.html?highlight=progress2#formatters)
- `-k` Don’t print skipped steps (due to tags)